# What would this non-'unique index with a unique search condition` query lock?

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking, transaction, isolation-level

I am not sure about this part of [the transaction manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read)

> For locking reads (SELECT with FOR UPDATE or LOCK IN SHARE MODE), UPDATE, and DELETE statements, locking depends on whether the statement uses a unique index with a unique search condition, or a range-type search condition. **For a unique index with a unique search condition, InnoDB locks only the index record found**, not the gap before it.
>
> **For other search conditions, InnoDB locks the index range scanned**, using gap locks or next-key (gap plus index-record) locks to block insertions by other sessions into the gaps covered by the range.

Maybe I'm just nitpicking, but I seem to read that there is a special condition in which "only the index record found" is locked (being: "unique index with unique search condition"). For all other we get some sort of range.

But what about 'other search conditions" that are nog a range? For istance, if I lock a query like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.col = 2`, there is no range or gaps in question, even if `col` is not unique, isn't there? Should we get a "only record found" lock here as well?

Comment: But there is a range, all rows with `table.col = 2` and `PK = whatever`

Comment: then maybe I don't understand 'range', but there is no range in the sense there could be gaps, is there? There will be a block on that `col=2` condition, not on any `PK`, is there?